# Create table on the fly using select into

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to use dynamic SQL to fill a temp table with data from one of several servers, depending on a declared variable.  The source data may have more columns added in the future, so I'd like to be able to create the destination temp table based on what columns currently exist, without having to explicitly define it.

I tried creating an empty table with the appropriate columns using:

```
Select top 1 * into #tempTable from MyTable
Delete from #tempTable
```

Or:

```
Select * into #tempTable from MyTable where 1 = 0
```

Both worked to create an empty table, but when I then try to insert into it:

```
declare @sql varchar(max) = 'Select * from ' 
+ case when @server = '1' then 'Server1.' else 'Server2.' end
+ 'database.dbo.MyTable'

Insert into #tempTable
    exec(@sql)
```

I get this error:

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 7, Line 1
>   Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

`exec(@sql)` works fine on its own.  I get this error even when I use the same table, on the same server, for both steps.  Is this possible to fix, or do I have to go back to explicitly defining the table with `create table`?

Comment: Does the user you're connecting with have a table "myTable" in it's schema that is structurally different than that on the server1 or server2?

Comment: No.  I tried this with the same server and table on both the `select into` and the `insert into`, and just selecting from #tempTable and MyTable to compare.  They appear to be identical.

Comment: I didn't think you can't combine the insert and exec that way. it all has to be dynamic SQL or none of it. try `exec('Insert into #tempTable '  + @sql)`

Comment: you need to supply the values.  `INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE (COL1,COL2,..etc) SELECT * FROM Server1.database.dbo.MyTable`, in which case you do not need to use exec(@sql) but rather build the string for Table Name after the FROM

Comment: @xQbert - Thanks!  That didn't turn out to be the problem, but did cause SQL to return a much more helpful error message.  Once I dropped the identity column, then the query worked as intended.

Comment: Comment out `Insert into #temptable` and see what results you get from just `exec(@sql)`.   This will show you which columns are different from your temp table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using global temp table. there is some disadvantage of using global temp table because it can access from multiple users and databases. ref   http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/temporary-tables-local-vs-global

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT * INTO ##tempTable FROM ' 
+ case when @server = '1' THEN 'Server1.' ELSE 'Server2.' END
+ 'database.dbo.MyTable'

EXECUTE sp_executesql (@sql)

SELECT * FROM ##tempTable
```

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't realize global temp tables worked like this in dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

(Thanks to helpful commenter @XQbert)

Replacing the `ID` column `(Int, Identity)` in the temp table with a column that was just an `int` causes

```
Insert into #tempTable
    exec(@sql)
```

to function as intended.

Both that syntax and

```
declare @sql varchar(max) = 'Insert into #tempTable Select * from ' 
+ case when @server = '1' then 'Server1.' else 'Server2.' end
+ 'database.dbo.MyTable'

exec(@sql)
```

worked, but making `insert` part of the dynamic sql produced much more helpful error messages for troubleshooting.